# net.ipv4 kernel variables affect on DPDK ports

Tags: dpdk

Sorry beforehand if this question is trivial or even if the answer is the question.

Our devices have an application that employees DPDK to use its NICs.
As part of the device setup some init done, part of it is settings kernel variables `net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl`, `tcp_max_syn_backlog`, `net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians` and etc

Do these kind of variables have any affect our ports under DPDK control?
Probably not, as DPDK is user space NICs, but I am not confident enough to assert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have NIC which are listed in `driver/net/` there are not much PMD devices which rely `net.ipv4` other than `TAP/TUN`. So if it is physical NIC one would not be affected.

[EDIT-1]
only Physcial NIC with userspace PMD (not tap representations) can be guaranteed to be not be affected like e1000, ixgbe, i40e, ice, fm10k etc are not affected. PMD like AF_PACKET/AF_XDP are also not affected while TAP/PCAP goes through linux stack

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please tell me whether I got you correctly:
1) DPDK Physical NICs are not affected from net.ipv4/6 setups
2) DPDK virtual NICs (TAP/TUN) are
3) Those kernel variables affect additionally (and mainly) only drivers whose KO are listed in /lib/modules/kernel-core/drivers/net/

Comment: yes only Physcial NIC with userspace PMD (not tap representations) can be guaranteed to be not be affected like e1000, ixgbe, i40e, ice, fm10k etc are not affected. PMD like AF_PACKET/AF_XDP are also not affected while TAP/PCAP goes through linux stack.

Comment: great, Ill accept that as an answer after you edit the answer to be more clear and informative as as in your comment

Comment: @Aviv the answer is edited you can accept and upvote